# How to make the div 100vh even if it has no children?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a simple page, which consists of a header, body, and footer. During the development, I want the content to have as much height as possible so that the entire page will have `100vh`. The problem is that if I only put some plain text content as the body(so no children tags for the body), it will look like this:

[image]

It's wrong because then I will have to add `height: 100%; width: 100%;` in every `children`'s style to make use of the full height of its parent. (imaging I pass a `<div className=...>...</div>` as the `children`)

This is the `page.tsx`:

```
import Footer from '@/components/Page/Footer'
import Header from '@/components/Page/Header'

import styles from './index.module.css'

interface PageProps {
  children: any
}

function Page({ children }: PageProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.page}>
      <Header />
      {children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

I already made `.page`:

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want the children content inside to grow and fill up all the available spaces within its `display: flex` parent, it will be a good time to use [flex-grow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow) property.

Try this:

```js
import Footer from '@/components/Page/Footer'
import Header from '@/components/Page/Header'

import styles from './index.module.css'

interface PageProps {
  children: any
}

function Page({ children }: PageProps) {
  return (
    <div className={styles.page}>
      <Header />
        <div className={styles.childrenContainer}>
          {children}
        </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Page
```

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.childrenContainer{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this promising solution! Is it possible to assign this property from the parent? Or maybe this would be a bad idea compared to yours?

Comment: Yes, in CSS you could use Combinators to assign CSS properties to its children elements in many ways you want. (Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors#combinators).

Comment: Oh, wait! I'm stupid. You already did that! this `<div>` will not be seen by the `children`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to insert `justify-content: space-between;` on the page class, and `margin-bottom:auto` for your content to stick to your header.